# Apache Camel 2.12: Adding bean to already existing context

Tags: java, apache-camel

I need to process a file on the app startup and create some objects out of the given information and then add them as beans to the camel context. Eg: Mysql DataSource object.

```
public static void load(CamelContext context) throws Exception {
    JndiRegistry registry = (JndiRegistry) context.getRegistry();
    PropertiesComponent pc = context.getComponent("properties", PropertiesComponent.class);
    pc.setLocation("classpath:mysql.properties");

    for (String mysql: pc.parseUri("{{mysqlConfigs}}").split(",")) {
        String MYSQL_DB_URL = pc.parseUri("{{" + mysql + ".url}}");
        String MYSQL_DB_USERNAME = pc.parseUri("{{" + mysql + ".username}}");
        String MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD = pc.parseUri("{{" + mysql + ".passwd}}");
        String DB_NAME = pc.parseUri("{{" + mysql + ".name}}");

        MysqlDataSource mysqlDS = new MysqlDataSource();

        mysqlDS.setURL(MYSQL_DB_URL);
        mysqlDS.setUser(MYSQL_DB_USERNAME);
        mysqlDS.setPassword(MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD);

        registry.bind(DB_NAME, (DataSource) mysqlDS);
    }

}
```

The code throws exception,

> org.apache.camel.impl.PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry cannot be cast to org.apache.camel.impl.JndiRegistry

Same error if I try to cast it to SimpleRegistry. Is there way this can be achieved this way or if any other methodology shall be adopted given that no more contexts are to be added.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
JndiRegistry registry = context.getRegistry(JndiRegistry.class);
```

Comment: This did not fix my issue. Can anyone add additional info?

Comment: Well, the comment was on an older version. You are probably on a newer version with another problem?